# How can you create a new role in OpenShift?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

Is there an API or command line that you can use to create or update a role in OpenShift ? I would like to create a new role so that a service account would only be able to do a deploy but now I am forced to grant the "edit" role to accomplish this which is way too much.

It seems it should be quite easy but I cannot find any documentation on this.

Comment: Can you explain better how that 'deploy' is going to happen? Do you mean you want to run an application in OpenShift, under a separate service account rather than 'default', which would then use the REST API to create a new application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Existing Documentation from Red Hat**

- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openshift_container_platform/3.3/html-single/cluster_administration/#manage-authorization-policy-creating-local-role

### Walkthrough:

**Minishift version used For testing commands in answer**

```
oc v1.5.1+7b451fc
kubernetes v1.5.2+43a9be4
features: Basic-Auth

Server https://192.168.99.100:8443
openshift v1.5.1+7b451fc
kubernetes v1.5.2+43a9be4
```

**Create new role**

*New role in yaml file named: exampleview.yaml*

File Contents:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: exampleview
rules:
- apiGroups: null
  attributeRestrictions: null
  resources:
  - pods
  - builds
  verbs:
  - get
    - list
    - watch
```

**Create role in project**

```
oc create -f exampleview.yaml -n myproject
```

*Authorization note! You must have permissions to grant extra privileges. In minishift you can grant the default user 'developer' these privileges easily by running:*

```
oc adm policy --as system:admin add-cluster-role-to-user cluster-admin developer
```

**Describe role in openshift after creating it**

```
oc describe role exampleview
```

**Remove role from project after creating it**

```
oc delete -f exampleview.yaml
```